# Навигация по сайту, как правильно?

Tags: html, html5, navigation

возникли проблемы с созданием навигационного меню. Как правильно это сделать? Можно ли  для вставки контента в "body" использовать `iframe>`, а с помощью меню менять ссылку содержимого `<iframe>`. Или нужно для каждого html документа вставлять навигационное меню ?

Comment: Почему iframe? Просто frame во frameset. Только так уже лет 15-20 никто не делает. Прямо сейчас вы на сайте, на котором есть «навигационное меню» слева.

Comment: хорошо, понял. Как правильно тогда сделать ?

Comment: Получается мне нужно на каждую страницу каждый раз добавлять в разметку навигационное меню?

Comment: Да, именно. Хорошо будет написать скрипт, который добавляет меню на страницу.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда ещё вопрос. Если при нажатии на ссылку отправить запрос на сервер через ajax, и подгрузить  другой документ ?

Comment: Через ajax можно получать новые данные и менять на странице.

Comment: Вообще стоит присмотреться к [компонентному подходу](https://learn.javascript.ru/webcomponents-intro).

Comment: Для компонентного подхода существует много фреймворков, например, [reactjs](https://ru.reactjs.org/)

Comment: Спасибо, думаю так и сделаю.

Comment: спасибо всем за ответы, я решил сделать через python django Jinja !